# SQL query needed for a complex structure

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a tricky SQL query that needs to be built to get the highest priority rule based on customer session and geo IP data.

I attached the following tables: rule, rule_attribute, rule_attribute_value.

**rule** - table where all rules are stored
[Click here to see a screenshot of the 'rule' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8GdL.png)

**rule_attribute** - table where all rule attributes are stored
[Click here to see a screenshot of the 'rule_attribute' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xly1d.png)

**rule_attribute_value** - table where all rule attribute values are stored
[Click here to see a screenshot of the 'rule_attribute_value' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YPcN.png)

When the customer logs in, I have access to all those attributes (customer_id, customer_group_id, country_id, subdivision_one_id, subdivision_two_id). Only customer_id and customer_group_id will always have values. The others are optional, but there is a dependency between them. We can't have subdivisions without selecting first a country. We can have a second subdivision without selecting a country and then the first subdivision.

What I would like to get is the highest priority rule that matches the session data in the most optimized way. I have a solution that involves some coding, but I want to see if it's possible directly through SQL.

Here are some examples of session data arrays:

```
Array
(
    [customer_id] => 2
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [current_store_id] => 0
    [country_id] => 15
    [subdivision_one_id] => 224
    [subdivision_two_id] => 
)

Array
(
    [customer_id] => 2
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [current_store_id] => 0
    [country_id] => 15
    [subdivision_one_id] => 
    [subdivision_two_id] => 
)

Array
(
    [customer_id] => 3
    [customer_group_id] => 2
    [current_store_id] => 0
    [country_id] => 
    [subdivision_one_id] => 
    [subdivision_two_id] => 
)
```

Comment: Please post data and code as text not images

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @iupaem Please remove your answer below and add the details to your question. Add your sample data, currently linked images, as markdown tables in your question and you will be more likely to get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a better understanding of the rules and data this is the best I can come up with. It is based on your first array example -

```sql
SELECT `r`.*
FROM `rule_attribute_value` `rav`
INNER JOIN `rule` `r`
    ON `rav`.`rule_id` = `r`.`rule_id`
INNER JOIN `rule_attribute` `ra`
    ON `rav`.`attribute_id` = `ra`.`attribute_id`
WHERE
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'customer'        AND `rav`.`value` = 2) OR
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'customer_group'  AND `rav`.`value` = 1) OR
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'country'         AND `rav`.`value` = 15) OR
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'subdivision_one' AND `rav`.`value` = 224)
GROUP BY `r`.`rule_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `rav`.`attribute_id`) = 4 /* 4 IS THE NUMBER OF ATTRIBUTES BEING QUERIED */
ORDER BY `r`.`position` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, @nnichols. It is working!